# Error when attempting to deploy a WAR to Glassfish 3 using an Ant Build Script

Tags: deployment, ant, glassfish-3, war

I am investigating how to use both Glassfish and Ant buildfiles. I've written a build script (for the first time) which will create a WAR file of my basic Hello World app.

I am then trying to deploy this WAR to Glassfish as part of the build script. I found details of the `glassfish-deploy` task and have managed to get this included in the build script after including the ant-task jar file in the class path.

However, when I run the script I get the message: 
`[glassfish-deploy] Install Directory of application server not known. Specify either the installDir attribute or the asinstall.dir property`

I've tried to find out what is meant by this, but can find no reference to either the installDir attribute or the asinstall.dir property. I have managed to deploy the created WAR file through Glassfish's admin webpage but I cannot seem to get this Ant script to do it successfully.

Any pointers or guidance would be most helpful.

Comment: OKay after a lightbulb moment I managed to resolve this by editing the task in my build script so it is now

    <glassfish-deploy file="${name}.war" installDir="C:\\glassfish3\\glassfish" force="true"/>
As it appears that the ant script does not know where Glassfish is installed. This resolves the issue but I think the next stage is to figure out how to do this without having to hardcode it into the build script.

Answer (score 0):

OKay after a lightbulb moment I managed to resolve this by editing the task in my build script so it is now `<glassfish-deploy file="${name}.war" installDir="C:\\glassfish3\\glassfish" force="true"/>`

As it appears that the ant script does not know where Glassfish is installed. This resolves the issue and the script runs (and workds) However the next stage is to figure out how to do this without having to hardcode the location into into the build script. Especially if I want to write a script that can deploy the WAR file to a remote server.